# Create table or only add changed/new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, alter-table

I have several tables which are worked on within a development environment, then moved to production. If they don't already exist in production, it's fine to just generate the table creation script from SSMS and run it. However, there are occasions where the table already exists in production but all that's needed is an extra column or constraint. The problem is knowing exactly what has changed.

Is there a way to get SQL to compare my `CREATE TABLE` statement against the existing table and only apply what has changed? Essentially I am trying to do the below and SQL correctly complains that the table exists already.

I would have to manually write an `ALTER` query which on a real example would be difficult due to the sheer volume of columns. Is there a better / easier way to see what has changed? Note that this involves two separate database servers.

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
( supplier_id int NOT NULL,
  supplier_name char(50) NOT NULL,
  contact_name char(50),
  CONSTRAINT suppliers_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);

CREATE TABLE suppliers
( supplier_id int NOT NULL,
  supplier_name char(50) NOT NULL,
  contact_name char(50),
  contact_number char(20), --this has been added
  CONSTRAINT suppliers_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);
```

Also, dropping and recreating wouldn't be a possibility because data would be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS can generate the schema change script if you make the change in the table designer (right-click on the table in Object Explorer and select Design). Then, instead of applying the change immediately, from the menu select Table Designer-->Generate Change Script. Note that depending on the change, SSMS may need to recreate the table, although data will be retained. SSMS requires you uncheck the option to "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" under Tools-->Options-->Designers-->Table and Database Designers. Review the script to make sure you're good with it.

SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and third-party tools (e.g. from Red-Gate and ApexSQL) have schema-compare features to generate the needed DDL after the fact. There are also features like migration scripts to facilitate continuous integration and source control integration as well. I suggest you keep database objects under source control and leverage database tooling as part of your development process.

Comment: Thank you - I've just tested generating a change script and it shows me the changes. That's good enough for this purpose! While I would love to employ source control both for code and databases, I'm limited hugely by a vendor SDK which doesn't have support for these types of features.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we use something like database migrations for this, as a feature outside of the database. For example, in several of our C# apps we have a tool called FluentMigrator. We write a script that adds the new columns we need in code, to the dev database. When the project is debugged, FM will run the script and modify the dev db, the dev code uses the new columns and all is well. FM knows not to run the script again

When time comes to put something live, the FM script is a part of the release, the app is put live onto the website, the migrations run again updating the live db so the live code will use the new columns and still all is well..

If there is nothing outside of your sql server (not sure how you manage that, but..), then surely you must be writing scripts (or using gui to generate scripts) that alter the DB right? So just keep those scripts and run them as part of the process of "going live"

If you are looking at this from a perspective that these db already exist created by someone else and they threw away the scripts, then you can one time catch up using a Database Schema Compare tool. Microsoft have one in SSDT - see here for more info on how it is used:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many constraints I suggest you create a dynamic script to cast and import the data into your new tables. If this doesn't fail then you just drop the old tables and rename the newly created ones.